# Is it possible to switch user ID during a Flurry session?

Tags: analytics, flurry

I have a multi user app with Flurry analytics. When the user switches user account in the app I want this to reflect in Flurry analytics. Currently the single user variant uses `setUserID(String)` to connect the user account to the session.

Does calling `setUserID(String)` again alter the remainder of the session or the whole? Or is it needed/possible to stop the Flurry session and start a new `startSession(String)`?

Answer (score 2):

A Flurry session can only have a single userID and this carries through the entire session. In general you should call setUserID(String) before the Flurry session begins. Calling setUserID a second time will not change the session userID.

Comment: So what should I do when a user logs out? End the flurry session?

Comment: Can you suggest How to get the user ID of a perticular user, should i use the login name or email id.